# In a Virtual Service, the routing rules of second matching condition are over ridden by first

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio, blue-green-deployment

The following Virual Service consists of matching conditions for routing the Live DNS and Test DNS to two different versions of same service. Here, based on the second matching condition, the Test DNS must route to the Green subset, but instead it is routing to the Blue subset (as we have mentioned, the weight 100 for blue in first matching condition). That means the second matching condition's routing rules are getting overridden by the first matching condition's routing rules.
All the indentations are also same.

Just as a brief

**So, now the routing should be**

**Live DNS--->Blue**

**Test DNS --->Green**

**But instead it is routing as**

**Live DNS--->Blue**

**Test DNS ---> Blue**

How to solve this issue?

```
 apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
 kind: VirtualService
 metadata:
   name: int-vs
   namespace: stdy-ns 
 spec:
   gateways:
   - int-gateway

   hosts:
   - live.dns.com
   - test.dns.com


   http:
   - match:
     - headers:
         host:
           exact: live.dns.com
       
     - uri:
         prefix: /internal/platform/service
     route:
     - destination:
         host: service
         subset: blue
       weight: 100
     - destination:
         host: service
         subset: green
       weight: 0
   - match:
     - headers:
         host:
           exact: test.dns.com
    
     - uri:
         prefix: /internal/platform/service
     route:
     - destination:
         host: service
         subset: green
```

Comment: How are you submitting the requests?  And are you sure you are properly setting the host header for the test/green requests?

Comment: Also, can you post your DestinationRule for "service"?

Comment: Hi @GariSingh , thanks for the response.
the Host header have set properly. So as the destination rules.

The issue was in the prefix being used. And it was figured out.